# How can I to create a shared directory from Redhat virtualbox vm to a Ubuntu 12.04 guest os?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, redhat, shared-directory

I have a 64bit Redhat VirtualBox (4.3.30) guest running and want to create an shared directory to my host OS (Ubuntu 12.04 64bit).
In my Redhat guest OS:

1. I installed VirtualBoxGuest Additions for Virtualbox 4.3.30 and
   rebooted the guest
2. I created the directory **/mnt/host-downloads** on my guest OS
3. In Virtual box I created a shared directory named Downloads with points to host directory **/home/cx/Downloads**

When I try to mount de shared directory with the command:
**sudo mount –t vboxsf Downloads /mnt/host-downloads**

I get the message:

"Usage: mount -V                 : print version
       mount -h                 : print this help
       mount                    : list mounted filesystems
       mount -l                 : idem, including volume labels
So far the informational part. Next the mounting.
The command is `mount [-t fstype] something somewhere'.
Details found in /etc/fstab may be omitted.
       mount -a [-t|-O] ...     : mount all stuff from /etc/fstab
       mount device             : mount device at the known place
       mount directory          : mount known device here
       mount -t type dev dir    : ordinary mount command
Note that one does not really mount a device, one mounts
a filesystem (of the given type) found on the device.
One can also mount an already visible directory tree elsewhere:
       mount --bind olddir newdir
or move a subtree:
       mount --move olddir newdir
One can change the type of mount containing the directory dir:
       mount --make-shared dir
       mount --make-slave dir
       mount --make-private dir
       mount --make-unbindable dir
One can change the type of all the mounts in a mount subtree
containing the directory dir:
       mount --make-rshared dir
       mount --make-rslave dir
       mount --make-rprivate dir
       mount --make-runbindable dir
A device can be given by name, say /dev/hda1 or /dev/cdrom,
or by label, using  -L label  or by uuid, using  -U uuid .
Other options: [-nfFrsvw] [-o options] [-p passwdfd].
For many more details, say  man 8 mount ."

**What do I wrong?**

Comment: Did you call the mount command in the guest os? Check if the Guest Additions are correctly installed (`lsmod | grep vboxsf` should produce output in the guest os). Afterwards you can check within the Guest OS with `sudo VBoxControl sharedfolder list` if the vm can see the **Downloads** share.

Comment: Both the commands "lsmod | grep vboxsf" and "sudo VBoxControl sharedfolder list" produce output.

Comment: "lsmod | grep vboxsf" gives:  2 lines of output. Line1: "vboxsf 37631 1"and line2 "vboxguest 261202 2 vboxsf". "sudo VBoxControl sharedfolder list"  gives 1 line of output: "01 Downloads". What should I do next?

Comment: I want also add, that I do all commands as root in ssh on my VM.

Comment: Ok, that means that the Guest Addons an the shared folder are correctly installed and configured.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this problem is the result of copy&pasting the command to the guest.

The hyphen (`–`)  in front of the `t` in the mount command is the unicode character *EN DASH* U+2013 (UTF-8 code 0xE28094) and not the dash (`-`) (U+002D) typed by the keyboard (see also http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pd/list.htm). This results in the usage displayed.

Solution:

Type the mount command by hand and don't use copy&past.

Comment: Thanks. I also found out if I use de command (even with use of copy past) it works. I use the command: "sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=$UID,gid=$(id -g) Downloads /mnt/host-downloads"

Comment: This is, because in this command you have the correct dash (minus) in front of the `t` flag and not, as in your OP,  the *EN DASH* character.